# Extract Metadata from uploaded Seurat Object in Shiny to make selectInput choices

Tags: r, shiny, seurat

I'm trying to create a Shiny App that will allow me to compare clusters from a Seurat object, and output a list of the differentially expressed genes. I've tried this so far:

```
#here's the UI portion I need help with:

          
      selectInput(inputId = "clusters", 
                  label = "Choose cluster 1: ", 
                  choices = NULL)

#here's the server function

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
#this is to load in the datasets reactively; i.e, they are not loaded until you select them
  
datasetInput <- reactive({
    if (input$dataset_selec == "NK AD Dataset") {
      dataset <- get(load("~/Desktop/Shiny App/Seuratapp/data/nk_integrated_object.Rdata"))
    }
    else if (input$dataset_selec == "APPPS1 Dataset") {
      dataset <- get(load("~/Desktop/ShinyApp/Seuratapp/data/appps1_lymphocytes_object.Rdata"))
    }
    else if (input$dataset_selec == "T Cell Infiltration Dataset") { 
      dataset <- get(load("~/Desktop/Shiny App/Seuratapp/data/tcell_infiltration.Rdata"))
    }
    return(dataset)
  })

#this is to transform the loaded dataset into something I can use as labels
  dataset <- datasetInput

  updateSelectInput(session, 
                    inputId = "metadata_split", 
                    label = "Choose category to split by: ",
                    choices = colnames(dataset@metadata))
```

This isn't working, I'm sure for a number of reasons, but frankly I'm having trouble understanding where to even start with this problem. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. Your code is incomplete. Make a [minimal reproducible example](https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-whats-a-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-create-one/5219) so that people can recreate your errors. For public Seurat data, you might try the [PBMC dataset](https://cf.10xgenomics.com/samples/cell/pbmc3k/pbmc3k_filtered_gene_bc_matrices.tar.gz) from the [Seurat tutorial](https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial.html#setup-the-seurat-object-1).
2. If `dataset` is supposed to be reactive, then I think that you need to [call the reactive expression](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/):

```
dataset <- datasetInput()
```

3. `dataset <- get(load(...))` is an unusual tactic. If you have `RData` objects, then you can do `dataset <- readRDS(...)`. See [here](https://github.com/ucdavis-bioinformatics/scRNA_shiny/blob/8bdadca03daf8e7ac9ef6d8e8226b0e06415949f/app.R#L11).